# Import Dependency Management with Exclusion

Tags: maven

I have a beautiful BOM with a lot of dependencies in its dependencyManagement section and I would like to **create another BOM** that imports all that dependencies **except one**. I tried doing this:

```
... in my dependencyManagement section
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
...
```

The POM is formally correct and everything compiles. **But the exclusion is simply ignored. What am I missing? Is this approach correct?**

I'm using Maven 3+.

Comment: You may need to provide the whole pom.xml, at the least the DependencyManagement and Dependencies sections

Comment: Also, type this "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.google.code.gson:gson" to show us where the dependency is really comming from

Comment: With [Maven 3.4.0 this will be supported](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5600) but unfortaneltey currently not.

Comment: Still not in Maven 3.5.2 Release as on date, this should be in the next maven version as the patch for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5600 has been pulled into master

Comment: Some recent activity https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/295, fingers crossed it will land in Maven 3.7!

Comment: Nope :( github.com/apache/maven/pull/295 is paused it seems

Comment: @khmarbaise Maven 3.4.0 has been a long time - what happened?

Comment: @Lonzak Take a look here: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Comment: @khmarbaise Sure maven version 3.4.0 was skipped. But then MNG-5600 could have been in 3.5, 3.6, 3.8 or 3.9 but unfortunately it isn't.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Exclusion at import won't work, try excluding it from the actual user of the dependency

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My maven version is 3.5.2. Just wanted to check is this feature added in maven in their latest version, so that i can exclude the dependency.

Comment: I misunderstood this, so for anyone reading, exclusions do work inside the dependencies declared at dependencyManagement tag, as long as they are not of the <scope>import</scope> (which only works with <type>pom</pom>)

Answer (score 19):

Exclusions are still not implemented for dependencyManagement import as of current maven 3.9.2. However you can include a project specific ["Bill Of Materials" (BOM)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms) as the first dependency in the dependencyManagement section, i.e.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my-group</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-group-project-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

You can then specify all the necessary artifact versions in your project BOM which will take precedence over the spring-boot dependency versions.

Comment: exclusions inside dependencyManagement do work, as long as they are not of scope import