# How to downgrade elasticsearch version When i use spring boot 2.4.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

How to downgrade elasticsearch version When i use spring boot 2.4.0??
I want to use elasticsearch version 6.6.0, but when using spring boot 2.4.0 version, even if 6.6.0 is specified in dependency, the dependency of version 7.9.4 is automatically used. How to downgrade elasticsearch version to 6.6.0 Do you have this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by adding this code to gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext {
        ...
        set('elasticsearch.version', '6.6.0')
    }
```

by using this code I can overriding elasticsearch's version to 6.6.0, even if i'm using spring boot veresion 2.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Exclusion at import won't work in maven !!

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <!-- define all downgraded version of elastic search dependencies here. I mean ALL -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>my-group</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-group-project-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63099817/8646703

Comment: Sorry, I'm using gradle, how do i define gradle?